# Some skeletons failed to generate with matplotlib in PyCharm

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I'm very new with Python. I'm working with PyCharm IDE on Windows. I'm trying to run some 3rd party code, but I'm having troubles with some functions that says "unresolved reference". These functions are: load, transpose and arctan.
For example:

```
z=load(dir+name+'.txt')
LBR=A*transpose(cos(B+C*(t)))
uu=arctan((bb/aa)*tan(phi))
```

I thought it was because of this library: `from pylab import *`, so I searched in the web and found that it was contain in a package named matplotlib, so I downloaded and installed it.

So now I haven't solved the first issue and I'm also getting this bug:

Some skeletons failed to generate: 12 modules failed in 1 interpreter.

[image]
This image shows the details of that last bug.

So, how do I fix this and which library or package should I use? Thanks.

Comment: How did you "download and install" matplotlib ? Pycharm has an integrated tool to install packages for interpreters. If you haven't used this feature already, I'd suggest uninstalling the matplotlib that is failing, and try installing again via Pycharm (`Preferences`|`Project`|`Project Interpreters`|`+`).

Comment: No, I downloaded an executable file and it installed it in the python path. Ill try it using your advice. Thanks.

Comment: Those files are related to the c-extensions so I am not surprised it failed.  Is this actually preventing pycharm from working?

Comment: No, the pycharm is working ok. Im downloading linux and downloaded already the pycharm for linux to see if it works in there. I already downloaded de C++ library for Python but I havent tried it yet.